# Is there an On Click Event when the user selects a row in a subform?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access application. The form `frmCustomersOrdersProducts` depicts Customers and their Orders. Therefore, the form contains two subforms `subfrmCustomerList` and `subfrmOrderList`. These two subforms are automatically created based on queries.

I want to show the orders for a particular customer when selecting a customer on the subform.

Unfortunately the subform provides only two events `On Enter` or `On Exit`. The `Detail` section of the form has an `On Click` event, but the method is not triggered when selecting a row.

What works is the `On Click Event` on certain fields / columns, for now I use the click event when the `ID` column is selected. But using the `On Click` event for every single column does seem very cumbersome?

Is there an `on-click` / `on-select` event for the whole row?

Comment: would `form_onCurrent` help? it will only be fired if any of your control get's focus (row selection would not set focus)

Comment: Row selection does trigger `Form_Current` of the subform. @krishKM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work in the subform(s), not the subform controls in the main form.

There you have the full set of events, including `On Current`.

To requery the order subform after selecting a customer record, you could have something like this in the customers form:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    ' subfrmOrderList is the name of the subform control (!) on the main form
    Me.Parent.subfrmOrderList.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

See here for more examples how to address subforms and their controls:
[Forms: Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)